# How to handle spaces with System.Process (system)

Tags: haskell, shellexecute

If I want to execute some string that contains another path with spaces (I can pass it alike `"\"C:/Program Files (x86)/G...`) `system` by default ignores quotes and shows error about `"C:/Program"`

Is there other quotes or I should replace space with some another symbol there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`rawSystem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.3.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:rawSystem) instead. It requires you to split the arguments in a list of strings, but at least you should not have any issues with spaces and escaping special characters.

Comment: Thank you but I still want to know if that is possible to handle spaces in `system`. Maybe I can make something that works like `system` based on `rawSystem`...